# Algolia - Wordpress disable indexing of whole taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I have thousands of tags, which I don't want to be indexed. How can I set Algolia plugin not to index `taxonomy_post_tag` and `post_author.display_name`?

Comment: I'd be glad to give you a detailed answer here, could you just give me a bit more context?
You say you have a lot of tags, by that you mean you have a lot of them per post? Ending up with a big array for taxonomy_post_tag inside your post records?
Could I ask also why you would want to remove the author display_name?

Comment: For the  author display_name - I have only 2 authors for all the posts and there is no need to be indexed. About the tags - I have about 10-20 tags per post in about 500 posts which leads to huge taxonomy_post_tag list with items in Algolia dashboard index. But if the search relies on tags to serve more relevant search results - that is okay. But I noticed something strange - all posts are being indexed 9 times instead of 1. See the screenshot, please: https://infinit.io/_/Ws8tuTP.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why you probably don't want to do it:

To begin with, I'm not sure the optimizations you are willing to do are worth the trouble.

Indeed, regarding usage quotas, Algolia doesn't care about your record size as long as you are under the limit put to 10kb per record. It could be a search optimization consideration though if you have lots of records, like 500k or more.

In your case you could probably keep the 2 attributes as they are in the records.

#### If you want to do it anyway:

If you really want to clean it up, you will have to remove the attributes from the records send to Algolia, which is fairly easy to achieve with a filter hook.

```
function my_post_shared_attributes( array $shared_attributes, WP_Post $post) {
  if ( isset( $shared_attributes['taxonomy_category'] ) ) {
    unset( $shared_attributes['taxonomy_category'] );
  }

  if ( isset( $shared_attributes['post_author'] ) ) {
    unset( $shared_attributes['post_author'] );
  }

  return $shared_attributes;
}
add_filter( 'algolia_post_shared_attributes', 'my_post_shared_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

#### Regarding each post being split into multiple Algolia records:

We split every post into multiple Algolia records based on the DOM structure of the post's content. This ensures no record will break the record size limit of 10kb, and even better, that it stays under 3kb most of the time which is optimal for the Algolia engine.

Comment: Thank you for everything! Now I see how different is ver. 0.3 compared to 0.1 regarding splitting the posts.